# Getting (null) while passing data between UIViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm confused. I have an UITableView and when I click on a row it performs a pushViewController with a new UIViewController. I want to pass data to this new view controller but my object is null. Here is the code I used :

```
//TableViewController.m
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MyObject *myObject = [myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    SecondViewController *vc = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
    vc.newObject = myObject;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}


//SecondViewController.h
@property (nonatomic, strong) MyObject *newObject;

//SecondViewController.m
@implementation SecondViewController
@synthesize newObject = _newObject;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
   NSLog(@"%@", _newObject);   // nil
}
```

That's strange because I always did things this way and it always worked before, I don't see why the returned value is null.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Have you checked what is the value of myObject after this line,  MyObject *myObject = [myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];?

Comment: Yes, for example if I do `NSLog(@"%@", myObject.name);` it returns "Test" but in the SecondViewController it returns "(null)"

Comment: Then check if you are resetting the newObject somewhere else like init method or so. Also change the NSLog to NSLog(@"%@", self.newObject); and try.

Comment: OMG, I'm ashamed.. You're right it's due to init method. I didn't think about it.. Thanks a lot ACB!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you are resetting `newObject` somewhere else like `init` method or so. Also change the `NSLog` to `NSLog(@"%@", self.newObject);` and try again.